# GWT: drawbacks of replacing IsSerializable with "interface IsSerializable extends Serializable"

Tags: java, serialization, gwt

In current GWT project I found a strange commit: the standard class **`com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.IsSerializable`** was replaced with the following code as a hack just to fix some serialization problems on the server side:

```
package com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc;

import java.io.Serializable;

public interface IsSerializable extends Serializable {
}
```

The **standard** definition of IsSerializable is (*gwt-user-2.8.1.jar*) is:

```
public interface IsSerializable {
}
```

To your mind, what are other **implications** of this, besides the ones I see:

1. side effects of overriding library classes,
2. possible problems with Java 9 jigsaw (I assume the GWT library code will become unchangeable) -> the application will never strictly comply with Java 9,
3. difficulties get back to the standard definition of IsSerializable as soon as this hack can be removed (code assuming Serializable when having IsSerializable, which would not be true after going back to standard).

In fact, I would like to know, if there are *other* dangerous implications which I do not see.

Answer (score 2):

The `IsSerializable` class pre-dates support in GWT-RPC for `java.io.Serializable`. You can avoid `IsSerializable` entirely, and only use `Serializable` in any GWT-RPC compatible objects.

Editing `IsSerializable` to extend `Serializable` should have no ill effects (aside from the Java 9 point), but likely can be avoided entirely if you simply don't use `IsSerializable` at all. That would be the proper solution here.

Answer (score 0):

I think that is a "trick" for GWT-rpc, in order to limit the amount of classes to export for serialization.
Hopefully someone closer to the core will step into this conversation and give more insight.

TL;DR: If you don't use GWT-rpc (you shouldn't) don't worry about it (I don't).